# How do I use an existing nginx server to serve LionWiki to my LAN only?

Tags: nginx, owncloud

Owncloud installed and is running Nginx on my network.  I can access my owncloud from outside my LAN.  I'd like to host a [Lionwiki](http://lionwiki.0o.cz/index.php?page=Main%20page) on my LAN only.

I would like to add a new config file to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` to serve a particular directory on the local network only.

My current config:

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default 
# owncloud (ssl/tls)
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name 192.168.1.10;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;
  root /var/www;
  index index.php;
  client_max_body_size 1000M; # set maximum upload size
  fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

  # deny direct access
  location ~ ^/owncloud/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
    deny all;
  }

  # default try order
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
  }

  # owncloud WebDAV
  location @webdav {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  # enable php
  location ~ ^(?<script_name>.+?\.php)(?<path_info>/.*)?$ {
    try_files $script_name = 404;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 900s; # 15 minutes
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your configuration currently?  Can you configure Nginx to listen on a specific address, or must it listen on all interfaces and only deny access for a specific path?  How is your network configured?  There isn't enough information to answer your question as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Setup two "hosting packages" for your nginx setup. One that listens to the public hostname of your owncloud and one that listens to the internal hostname and / or the internal ip. Then you can access your Owncloud via http://the-host-name-you-have.chosen and your wiki via \SERVERNAME or your internal IP, e.g. 192.168.0.3

Your config could then look somewhat like:

```
server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  SERVERNAME;

            access_log  logs/localhost.access.log  main;

            location / {
                root /var/www/lionwiki;
                index index.html index.htm index.php;
            }

            listen       80;
            server_name  public-host-name;

            access_log  logs/localhost.access.log  main;

            location / {
                root /var/www/owncloud;
                index index.html index.htm index.php;
            }
       }
```

Note: I am not 100% sure if that syntax is right, I usually work with IIS.